# Declarar uma classe com nome de uma palavra reservada é uma boa ideia?

Tags: php, sintaxe, palavras-reservadas

Geralmente, quando vamos definir nomes para classe e funções, há uma preocupação quando à colisão com as `palavras-chaves` da linguagem.

O curioso é que eu observei que, no PHP, é permitido definir classe e funções com o mesmo nome de certas palavras chaves.

## Definições que não geram erros

Para os seguinte exemplos abaixo, a definição NÃO gera erros.

```
class Int{}

class Object{}

class String{}
```

Inclusive no `Cakephp` existe uma classe que se chama `Object`. E, no `ZendFramework`, existe `Zend\Form\Annotation\Object`.

E ainda temos as funções. 
Observe que chega a parecer contraditória a declaração abaixo:

```
function int($int)
{
    return (int) $int;
}

var_dump(int('1')); // int(1)
```

## Definições que geram erro

Nos exemplos abaixo, utilizei duas palavras chaves. Uma muito comum, que é `array`, e outra é a que foi adicionada na versão `5.4` do PHP, que é `callable`.

```
class Callable{}

class Array{}
```

E temos o seguinte resultado:

> syntax error, unexpected 'Callable' (T_CALLABLE), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
>
> syntax error, unexpected 'Array' (T_ARRAY), expecting identifier (T_STRING)

## As perguntas

- Devo me preocupar em **não declarar** classes e funções com o nome dessas palavras-chaves descritas acimas (quer aceitas na declaração, quer não)?
- Ou não há problema ao fazer isso, visto que os famosos frameworks supracitados utilizam dessa prática?
- Existe alguma recomendação quando a quais nomes podem ser usados ou não usado, quando se trata de um nome de uma `palavra-chave`? Pois quando é que eu vou saber que eu "estou liberado" para declarar uma classe com tal nome específico.

## Nota

Queria apenas deixar registrado um problema que ocorreu para quem usava versões framework `Laravel 3`. Nele havia uma função chamada `yield`. O `Laravel 3` foi desenvolvido para o `PHP 5.3`. Porém, mais tarde, o `PHP 5.5` "inventou" a palavra reservada `yield`, que fez com que o `Laravel 3` não funcionasse no PHP 5.5, pois gerava um `E_PARSE`. E assim desenvolvedor teria que ficar preso entre a versão 5.3 e 5.4 do PHP, caso mantivesse o `Laravel 3`.

Comment: E se a linguagem permitir que algumas palavras reservadas sejam usadas em métodos e te deixasse mais a vontade para desenvolver suas classes da forma que você quiser? https://wiki.php.net/rfc/context_sensitive_lexer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na realidade você não pode usar as palavras reservadas (os chamados construtores de linguagem) em nenhum lugar. As funções que você conseguiu criar e funcionaram (`Int`, `String`, `Object`) não são [palavras reservadas, conforme a documentação](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.keywords.php).

Você não precisa se preocupar na declaração de métodos e funções em relação as palavras-chave já existentes. Você consegue colocar elas nas variáveis, mas pode causar algumas confusões.

O interessante é evitar expressões que podem ser possíveis palavras reservadas no futuro, como `int`, `string`, `float`. Com a proposta de [type hinting de tipos primitivos](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/scalar_type_hints_v5) no PHP 7 e um [novo operador na linguagem](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/in_operator), novas palavras reservadas podem surgir, conforme já proposto [aqui](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/reserve_even_more_types_in_php_7) e [aqui](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/reserve_more_types_in_php_7).

Os problemas que podem ocorrer são de incompatibilidade com códigos legados, como você exemplificou com a palavra `yield` no Laravel 3 (não me lembro se foi criado um patch para corrigir isso).

Para amenizar esse tipo de situação, está em fase de votação uma proposta que permite o uso de algumas [palavras reservadas no escopo de métodos](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/context_sensitive_lexer). Isso permitiria ao desenvolvedor mais liberdade ao nomear seus métodos e evitaria esse tipo de incompatibilidade descrita acima.

Com essa proposta aprovada, poderíamos desenvolver códigos mais expressivos como esse abaixo:

```
class Collection extends \ArrayAccess, \Countable, \IteratorAggregate {

    public function forEach(callable $callback) {
        //...
    }

    public function list() {
        //...
    }

    public static function new(array $itens) {
        return new self($itens);
    }
}

Collection::new(['foo', 'bar'])->forEach(function($index, $item){
  /* callback */
})->list();
```

Answer (score 3):

Vamos por partes:

> Devo me preocupar em não declarar classes e funções com o nome dessas
>   palavras-chaves descritas acimas (quer aceitas na declaração, quer
>   não)?

Sim. Você deve evitar usar qualquer palavra reservada na declaração de suas variaveis/classes/metodos.

> Ou não há problema ao fazer isso, visto que os famosos frameworks
>   supracitados utilizam dessa prática?

Há problemas em fazer isso. Uma miriade de anomalias pode ocorrer, desde na atualização do PHP (no seu caso) até manutenções posteriores.

> Existe alguma recomendação quando a quais nomes podem ser usados ou
>   não usado, quando se trata de um nome de uma palavra-chave? Pois
>   quando é que eu vou saber que eu "estou liberado" para declarar uma
>   classe com tal nome específico.

Em teoria o manual da linguagem deveria constar se alguma palavra reservada pode ser usada, mas eu duvido muito que o PHP tenha isso. Primeiramente porque, em teoria, palavras reservadas são... bem, reservadas para a interpretação/compilação correta do código.

Acredito que você está encontrando essas confusões por conta do PHP, que tenta partir de um pressuposto de "rodar sempre que possivel". Muito provavelmente outras linguagens não permitiriam usar palavras reservadas em nenhum caso, por isso, não faz muito sentido ficar tentando achar as palavras reservadas que podem ser usadas como nomes de classes/metodos.

Comment: Só descordo das variáveis no caso específico do PHP, pois ele tem sempre `$` antes.